# ReactRouterDom, trigger an event on page change

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom

I have a component that is a navigation bar. The navigation bar persists within all screens in specific parts of my project, and is the highest level component at all given times.

Is it possible to somehow get a page-change event  (so if I go from say, /main/viewer to /main/documents ) without having a callback triggering a pagechange going from navigation bar all the way down to the viewer component?

These components are nested in each other, as the NavBar displays main screen, which then directs to different component for different screens, which in turn have components that call different screens based on buttons pressed, etc etc.

I'm trying to get the simplest way to get a page-change event, so that I can trigger a function in viewer, which prompts to save any edits done, if page is about to be changed through the nav-bar (or another means) and not via a button in the viewer.

currently, I navigate between pages/components by using `this.,props.history` and then either `.push("path", props)` and `.goBack()` which is usually the last line on a function to handle exiting the component.

Comment: Use the `useLocation` hook with an `useEffect` hook with the `location.pathname` as a dependency. If you are using RRDv5, and it sounds like you are, you can even instantiate a [history listener](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/v4/docs/GettingStarted.md#listening) instead. Also, from what you describe, it's perhaps even easier than you think, just use an `useEffect` hook alone with the logic you describe in the returned cleanup function. You don't really need to listen for route changes, you want to run some code before the component unmounts.

Comment: Will look into it a bit more then when I have a moment.
The only complexity here, is that I write in class, rather than functional components, so using `useEffect` is a bit out of the question.
But from what I understand, is that I might have to put in a `componentDidUnmount()`, and call a function in there?

Comment: Use the `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods then.

Comment: I've not used Unmount before, as I didn't realize it could do that! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)